# Email sent using Contact Form 7 shows <a> tag code not a formatted link

Tags: php, formatting, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 plugin with this addon "Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension" which allows you to use shortcodes to add data to your emails and form elements
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/

I created a shortcode that based on the current page adds a link to a PDF file in the Autoresponder email that is sent.

```
function get_pdf_link( $atts ) {
    global $post;

    switch ($post->post_title) {
        case 'Agency':
            return '<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://example.com/qcmresearch/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Agency-Evaluation-Checklist.pdf">Download the Agency Evaluation Checklist</a>';
            break;
        case 'Signup':
            return '<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://example.com/qcmresearch/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/signup.pdf">Download the Signup Options</a>';
            break;
        default:
            return '<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://example.com/qcmresearch/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Agency-Evaluation-Checklist.pdf">Download the Agency Evaluation Checklist</a>';
            break;
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'CF7_EBOOK_DOWNLOADFILE', 'get_pdf_link' );
```

The value from the shortcode gets added to the autoresponder email correctly but the a tag is not formatted into html and displays as code:

```
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Agency-Evaluation-Checklist.pdf">Download the Agency Evaluation Checklist</a>
```

It should be formatted like this

**Download the Agency Evaluation Checklist**

I manually added the same link to the message body in Wordpress and it looked fine so there is something with the shortcode or how I added my link that is breaking the formatting.

Update:
I inspected the `<a>` tag in developer tools @ Yahoo mail and it is wrapped in parenthesis not sure why though `"<a ...>Download the Agency Evaluation</a>"`

Comment: I guess your tag-string gets escaped somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Use html_entity_decode function:

```
function get_pdf_link( $atts ) {
global $post;

switch ($post->post_title) {
    case 'Agency':
        return html_entity_decode('<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://example.com/qcmresearch/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Agency-Evaluation-Checklist.pdf">Download the Agency Evaluation Checklist</a>');
        break;
    case 'Signup':
        return html_entity_decode('<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://example.com/qcmresearch/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/signup.pdf">Download the Signup Options</a>');
        break;
    default:
        return html_entity_decode('<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://example.com/qcmresearch/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Agency-Evaluation-Checklist.pdf">Download the Agency Evaluation Checklist</a>');
        break;
}
}
add_shortcode( 'CF7_EBOOK_DOWNLOADFILE', 'get_pdf_link' );
```